# Which SFF author wrote her first novel during recess while she worked as a teacher?

Tags: authors

Some time ago, probably in the late 1980s or early 1990s, I read an interview with one of the science fiction or fantasy writers I was reading at the time. In that interview, the author stated that she had been writing her first novel during the breaks at the school where she was working as a teacher. I always thought it was Anne McCaffrey, but there is no indication she ever was a teacher. C. J. Cherryh was a teacher, but her Wikipedia page says she wrote "in her spare time away from teaching", which seems to indicate that she wrote at home (or at least not in school). Ursula K. Le Guin, my third possible candidate, didn't teach at school.

Anyone know which author said she wrote her first book in the recesses / breaks during her time as a school teacher?

Comment: For sure teaching?  Not in the wings/backstage during a theater career?  Because that would be Madeleine L'Engle...

Comment: C. J. Cherryh started writing *Gate of Ivrel* during her free time when she was still *in* high school.

Comment: Andre Norton wrote *her* first novel "in the school hall" while still in high school.

Comment: Phyllis Eisenstein was a teacher for many years and wrote her first novel in 1977 I think while she was a teacher

Comment: Connie Willis started writing when she was a teacher.

Comment: Zenna Henderson was a teacher for most of her life.  I know for a fact that she would write before and after school, but I cannot prove that she wrote her first story this way.

Comment: @Buzz Do you have a source for that? (Only if you remember where you learned that. You don't have to do my research for me.)

Comment: @DoscoJones I thought of Zenna Henderson too, but that seemed unlikely, since she died in 1983.

Comment: @Ben If you mean about Willis, I don't know where I first learned it, but I think it's pretty well known.  I just checked, and it's right there on her Wikipedia page.

Comment: @Ben, it's a childhood memory.  My father wrote to M. Henderson a number of times, and she always responded.  He'd read her response letters to me, and the before/after school thing was something she wrote about.

Comment: @Buzz Ooops, I just noticed you had posted two comments. I meant C. J. Cherryh.